# Apache Ignite .net thin client "Too many open cursors" exception

Tags: .net, ignite

Getting the following exception from the .net thin client performing both linq and SQL queries against an ignite cache

> Exception : "Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.IgniteClientException: 50000: Too many open cursors (either close other open cursors or increase the limit through ClientConnectorConfiguration.maxOpenCursorsPerConnection) [maximum=128, current=128]
> at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.HandleError[T](ClientStatusCode status, String msg) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DecodeResponse[T](BinaryHeapStream stream, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)
> at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc)
> at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.Query[T](SqlFieldsQuery sqlFieldsQuery, Func`3 readerFunc)
> at Apache.Ignite.Linq.Impl.CacheFieldsQueryExecutor.ExecuteSingle[T](QueryModel queryModel, Boolean returnDefaultWhenEmpty)
> at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSingleValueInfo.ExecuteSingleQueryModel[T](QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
> at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSingleValueInfo.ExecuteQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
> at Apache.Ignite.Linq.Impl.CacheFieldsQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)

The client application uses both Apache.Ignite.Linq and SQL Queries IFieldsQueryCursor

many of the sql queries use the Select clause to transform the IFieldsQueryCursor result into a IEnumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can change the `ClientConnectorConfiguration.maxOpenCursorsPerConnection` property (on your Ignite server nodes) to increase the number of cursors that can be opened simultaneously.

Having said that, 128 sounds plenty! Are you sure you're closing all your cursors when you're finished with them? They're `IDisposable`, so it's a good idea to put them in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache.Ignite.Linq you don't have to worry about closing query cursors, but `IFieldsQueryCursor` must be closed with `Dispose`.

Looks like you are doing something like `cache.QueryFields(qry).Select(...)...`, which keeps the cursor open. Instead, try something like

```cs
using (var cursor = cache.QueryFields(qry))
{
    cursor.Select(...)...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. will change the code and run it through the load test again